# Iterate though the contents of a Map<String,List<Object>> and assign the values of the List<Object> into separate List<Double>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, java-8

I have a `list` of objects that contain `coordinates` and a `name`. An example of the printed list can be seen below:

```
[X=0.1, Y=0.1, name=Series1]
[X=0.1, Y=0.2, name=Series1]
[X=0.1, Y=0.3, name=Series1]
[X=0.1, Y=0.4, name=Series2]
[X=0.1, Y=0.5, name=Series2]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to group them together based on the `name` which can be done with the following Java 8 operation:

```
Map<String, List<Coordinates>> newList = coordinateList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Coordinates::getName));
```

Output:

```
Series1=[[X=0.1, Y=0.1],[X=0.1, Y=0.2],[X=0.1, Y=0.3]]
Series2=[[X=0.1, Y=0.4],[X=0.1, Y=0.5]]
```

The final step which I have not yet been able to achieve, is to iterate through the `Map`, create lists of `X's` and `Y's` so I can finally create a graph (`chart.addSeries(name, xData, yData);)`.

My approach to this so far has been the following:

```
    List<Double> xData = new LinkedList<Double>();      
    List<Double> yData = new LinkedList<Double>();

    newList.forEach((k, v) -> {
        //TO-DO
    });
```

Inside the `loop` I would like to assign `X's` and `Y's` to the corresponding `lists` but with no success so far.

One of the problems is that `X` and `Y` are associated with a `Coordinates` object, so I cannot just add them to the `list` which is of type `Double`. Another problem I faced is that I cannot get `X` and `Y` separately from the `list`. I have tried `getX()` and `getY()` but with no luck.

Example of what I would like the lists to contain:

For the `key` `Series1` the generated `lists` would be the following:

```
xData=[0.1,0.1,0.1]
yData=[0.1,0.2,0.3]
```

For the next key Series 2:

```
xData=[0.1,0.1]
yData=[0.4,0.5]
```

Comment: *I have tried getX() and getY() but with no luck*. Please complete your example to show what you would like those lists to contain, show what you have tried, tell precisely what you expected to happen and what happened instead. And don't use LinkedList. There's really no reason. Use an ArrayList.

Comment: I added an example of the outcome I would like to achieve.

Comment: Now, show what you have tried, tell precisely what you expected to happen and what happened instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `forEach`, `(k, v)` represents the key and the value of each pair, so you need to get the `Coordinates` and then its x and y. Also as you don't need specificly a `LinkedList`, use an `ArrayList`.

As you want a Series for each pair, your `xData` and `yData` should be in the loop :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Coordinates>> serie : newList.entrySet()) {
    List<Double> xData = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> yData = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Coordinates coord : serie.getValue()) {
        xData.add(coord.getX());
        yData.add(coord.getY());
    }

    chart.addSeries(serie.getKey(), xData, yData);
}
```

---

Choose first option as it's easier to use, don't use `forEach` to quickly :

```
newList.forEach((key, value) -> {
    List<Double> xData = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> yData = new ArrayList<>();

    value.forEach(c -> {
        xData.add(c.getX());
        yData.add(c.getY());
    });

    chart.addSeries(key, xData, yData);
});
```

---

With `Stream` api you can move to :

```
newList.forEach((key, value) -> {
   List<Double> xData = value.stream().map(Coordinates::getX).collect(Collectors.toList());
   List<Double> yData = value.stream().map(Coordinates::getY).collect(Collectors.toList());
   chart.addSeries(key, xData, yData);
});
```

Comment: I get the error `The method getX() is undefined for the type List<Coordinates>`

Comment: @JohnStef yep this has nothing to do with this code

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using collect iterating on Coordinate list as:

```
List<Double> xData = coordinateList.stream()
            .map(Coordinates::getX)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

where `coordinateList` is `List<Coordinate>` as used previously for grouping and this is collecting to `LinkedList` as stated in the question OR you could do both the lists in a single iteration

```
coordinateList.forEach(coordinates -> {
    yData.add(coordinates.getY());
    xData.add(coordinates.getX());
});
```

***Note***: I've used `coordinateList` considering, it has not been altered pre or post the grouping statement as shared in the question.

---

You might though be looking for xData and yData series or each iteration and that might account for `List<List<Double>>` as output which can be achieved as :

```
List<List<Double>> xDatas = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Double>> yDatas = new ArrayList<>();
newList.forEach((k,v) -> {
    xDatas.add(v.stream()
            .map(Coordinates::getX)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)));
    yDatas.add(v.stream()
            .map(Coordinates::getY)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)));
});
```